# Implement a ButtonToggleGroupComponent in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, material-design

I am very new to react and I want to implement a simple ButtonToggleComponent and a ButtonToggleGroupComponent. The second component contains **n** amount of ButtonToggleComponents and has some logic. The ButtonToggleGroupComponent should allow only one ButtonToggleComponent to be active at the same time like the behavior of a radio control. Also, the first and last ButtonToggleComponent should not have rounded corners on one side like the [material-button](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/buttons/#raised-buttons) I use for this component.

**My approach:**

**ButtonToggleComponent:**

```
class ButtonToggleComponent extends React.Component {
    _label;
    _isFirst;
    _isLast;
    _classes;

    constructor({label, isFirst, isLast, classes}) {
        super();
        this._label = label;
        this._isFirst = isFirst;
        this._isLast = isLast;
        this._classes = classes;
    }

    get Label() {
        return this._label;
    }

    get IsFirst() {
        return this._isFirst;
    }

    get IsLast() {
        return this._isLast;;
    }

    get Classes() {
        return this._classes;
    }

    getCorrectCornerStyles() {
        if(this.IsFirst) {
            return {
                borderTopRightRadius: "0",
                borderBottomRightRadius: "0"
            }
        }
        else if(this.IsLast) {
            return {
                borderBottomLeftRadius: "0",
                borderTopLeftRadius: "0"
            }
        }
    }

    render() {
        return <Button raised color="primary" className="buttonToggle" style={this.getCorrectCornerStyles()}>
            <label className={this.Classes.buttonLabel}>{this.Label}</label>
      </Button>
    }
}
```

**ButtonToggleGroupComponent:**

```
class ButtonToggleGroupComponent extends React.Component {
    _buttonToggleChildren;
    _classes;

    constructor({ children, classes }) {
        super();
        this._buttonToggleChildren = children;
        this._classes = classes;
    }

    get ButtonToggleChildren() {
        return this._buttonToggleChildren;
    }

    get Classes() {
        return this._classes;
    }

    render() {
        return <div>
            { this.ButtonToggleChildren }
        </div>
    }
}
```

**How to use:**

```
<ButtonToggleGroupComponent>
          <ButtonToggleComponent isFirst={true} label="a" />
          <ButtonToggleComponent isLast={true} label="s" />
        </ButtonToggleGroupComponent>
```

**Display:**

[image]

As you can see I pass two props (isFirst, isLast) down to the ButtonToggleComponent with which I can apply the correct styles for the corners, but I think this is not the cleanest solution or in other words no best practice solution. How can I do this without passing props? Because it is every time the first and the last ButtonToggleGroupComponent where I have to apply these styles. Or should I do this completely different?

Also, I have no idea how to implement that function that always only one ButtonToggleComponent can be active. A little background: this is a new project and I want to design the components first before I start with state management(we want to use redux) and create actions and stuff like that. So it would be nice if this component could do this function that only ButtonToggleComponent at the same time can be active without a state. Is this possible anyway?

If you notice other things that could be done better so please feel free to mention that. It would be very valuable for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use React.Children in your container, it will allow you to set the style for the component in the container, you will still need the prop you just won't have to enter in manually. This would also allow you to add customizations like other props to the parent class and it can pass them to all of the buttons internally.

Something like:

```
    {React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child, index) => (
      if(index === 0) {
        React.cloneElement(
          child,
          {
            isFirst
          }
        )
      }
      else if (index === React.Children.count - 1) {
        // Same as above but with isLast
      }
      else {
        React.cloneElement(child);
      }
    ))}
```

Edit: It's a little verbose for what you are trying to do though so it might be better to use css properties (`:last-child` and :`first-child`) to do this.

Comment: Is it possible to use these css properties in JSS? Because I want to use the [Material-UI CSS in JS](https://material-ui-next.com/customization/css-in-js/) feature for styling my components. Do you know that maybe?